# MySQLi запрос из функции

Tags: php, ооп, mysqli

Я выполняю функцию

```
function test($uid) {
$data = array(
    'uid' => $uid,
    'bla' => $bla,
    'bla1' => $bla1,
    'bla2' => $bla2);
db::insert("chat",$data);
}
```

а он показывает мне такую ошибку

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method DB::insert() should not be called statically

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
```

ООП MySQLi

```
class DB {

    protected $db_name = 'test';
    protected $db_user = 'root';
    protected $db_pass = 'root';
    protected $db_host = 'localhost';


    public function connect() {
        $this->db = mysqli_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass,$this->db_name);
        return true;
    }

    public function insert($table, $data) {
        $columns = "";
        $values = "";
        foreach ($data as $column => $value) {
            $columns .= ($columns == "") ? "" : ", ";
            $columns .= '`'.$column.'`';
            $values .= ($values == "") ? "" : ", ";
            $values .= "'".$value."'";
        }
        $sql = "insert into $table ($columns) values ($values)";
        mysqli_query($this->db, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
        return mysql_insert_id();
    }
}

$db = new DB();

$db->connect();
```

Помимо `insert`, есть и, например, `DELETE`

```
public function delete($table, $where) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `$table` WHERE $where";
    mysqli_query($this->db, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
    return true;
}
```

который находится в этом же классе, но `delete` работает без ошибок.

Когда присваиваю `static` к `insert`, то остаётся только вторая ошибка, но `delete` при таких же условиях почему-то не нуждается в `static`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите сделать методы статичными, то не должны использовать в них `$this`, так как `$this` ссылается на текущий объект, которого у вас нет.

Добавлю от себя:

- если уж вы используете ООП, то почему не использовать объектный подход у MySQLi?
- метод connect можно переделать в конструктор, тогда отпадает необходимость вызывать какой-либо метод для соединения с БД
- не забывайте обрабатывать данные, у вас возможна SQL-инъекция
- почитайте про стандарты кодирования (PSR, Zend, PEAR)

Comment: а еще добавлю про вырвиглазное форматирование. И такие конструкции

    $columns .= ($columns == "") ? "" : ", ";
    $columns .= '`'.$column.'`';
    $values .= ($values == "") ? "" : ", ";
    $values .= "'".$value."'";

лучше все-таки решать через доп.массив и `implode()`

Comment: @Etki, добавил в ответ. Так же не за чем делать свойства с данными для подключения к БД защищенными, можно сделать их константами класса или закрытыми.

Comment: @windirprog, самый банальной способ - использование сверхпростого паттерна Registry:

    class Registry
    {
        protected static $storage = array();
        public static function get($name)
        {
            return static::$storage[$name];
        }
        public static function set($name, $value)
        {
            static::$storage[$name] = $value;
        }
    }

После этого подключение запихивается в реестр один раз и выводится сколько угодно

    Registry::set('db', mysqli_connect(/*...*/));

В любом другом месте

    /** @type mysqli $db */
    $db = Registry::get('db');

Answer (score 2):

Следует понимать, что помимо мелкой частной проблемы со статическим вызовом, в этом классе присутствует множество других проблем, принципиальных и фатальных.

И в первую очередь это **полная открытость к SQL инъекциям**.

О некоторых других проблемах сказали выше, плюс множество мелких проблем. Например, гомерическая конструкция `die(mysql_error());`, в которой неверно всё: здесь не должно быть ни `mysql_error()`, ни `die()`. или, скажем, бессмысленные переменные класса с параметрами соединения.

И, наконец, здесь принципиально неверный подход к организации подобного класса. [Я уже разбирал схожий случай](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/420004/179379), поэтому не буду повторяться.