# Оцените класс для работы с MySql

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, инспекция-кода

Недавно написал класс для работы с MySql.
Прошу посмотреть, есть ли в этом классе дырки (sql injection).
Каждая строка подписана для понимания кода.

```php
<?php
Class bd{
    private $mysqli;

    public function connect($cfg){//Функция подключения ,при вызове передаём настройки с данными от бд
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($cfg['bd']['host'], $cfg['bd']['user'], $cfg['bd']['password'], $cfg['bd']['name']);//подключение к бд
        $this->mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");//установка кодировки
        $this->mysqli->set_charset("utf8");//установка кодировки
    }

    public function get($table,$columns='*',$filter=false){//функция для получения данных из бд ,при вызове передаём: название таблица, [название столбцов], [дополнительный sql фильтр]
        $filter = ($filter !== false)? ' WHERE '.$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($filter):'';//получаем данные из бд
        return $this->changeToArray($this->mysqli->query("SELECT $columns FROM `$table`".$filter));//преобразовываем их в двух мерный массив и возращяем
    }

    public function add($table,$data){//добавления данных в бд, при вызове передаём: названия таблицы, массив вида 'название столбца'=>'данные'
        $keys = '';//тут будут хранится название столбцов
        $values = '';//тут будут хранится вносимые данные
        foreach($data as $key=>$val) {//перебор входящего массива
            if(gettype($val) !== 'string' || gettype($val) !== '"integer"') $val = json_encode($val);//если переданые данные не явлиются ,не строкой и не числом преобразовываем их в json-данные
            $keys .= '`'.$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($key).'`, ';//добавляем новое название столбца
            if(gettype($val) === 'integer') $values .= $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($val).' , ';//добавляем новые данные
            else $values .= '\''.$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($val).'\', ';//добавляем новые данные
        }
        $keys = substr($keys, 0, -2);//обрезаем лишний пробел и запятую
        $values = substr($values, 0, -2);//обрезаем лишний пробел и запятую
        $this->mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `$table` ($keys) VALUES ($values)");//добалвяем данные в БД
    }

    public function edit($table,$filter,$data){//функция редактирования, при вызове передаём: названия таблицы,фильтр, массив вида 'название столбца'=>'данные'
        $sql_data = '';//тут будет хранится sql запрос
        foreach($data as $key=>$val) {//переберам данные
            if(gettype($val) !== 'string' || gettype($val) !== '"integer"') $val = json_encode($val);//если переданые данные не явлиются ,не строкой и не числом преобразовываем их в json-данные
            if(gettype($val) === 'integer') $sql_data = '`'.$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($key).'`='.$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($val).', ';//добавляем новые данный в sql запрос
            else $sql_data = '`'.$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($key).'`=\''.$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($val).'\', ';//добавляем новые данный в sql запрос
        }
        $sql_data = substr($sql_data, 0, -1);//обрезаем линюю запятую
        $this->mysqli->query("UPDATE `$table` SET $sql_data WHERE ".$filter);//обновляем данные в бд
    }

    public function delete($table,$filter=false){//функция удаления ,при вызове передаём: название таблицы, [фильтр]
        $filter = ($filter !== false)? ' WHERE '.$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($filter):'';//если фильтр равен false присваевам ему постое значение
        $this->mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `$table`".$filter);//удаляем данные из бд
    }

    private function changeToArray($result) {//внутреняя функция для преобразования sql данных в двухмерный массив
        if($result===false) return array();
        $results = array();
        while(($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) != false) $results[] = $row;
        return $results;
    }

    public function __destruct() {//функция закрытия соединения.
        $this->mysqli->close();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Нет работы с плейсхолдерами => сразу в /dev/null.

Comment: Mr_Epic, для хранения и выкладывание в публичный доступ кода есть специальные сервисы - закрывающийся google code, bitbucket, github.

Comment: вместо `bd` должно быть `db` =) "data base". Вот, залил на pastebin: http://pastebin.com/X5Dq7DFi

Comment: все плохо `#ооп` `#кэнтБэк` `#мартин` `#codingStandards` - это на почитать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Хотел ответить и забыл. Я не претендую на полный разбор, я просто покажу те места, которые, на мой взгляд, следовало бы переправить в кратчайшие сроки.

```
<?php
Class bd{
```

Первая проблема - это форматирование. `Class` всегда пишется с маленькой буквы, название класса - с большой, т.н. `StudlyCaps`, при этом название класса должно явно говорить о том, что он делает (не `bd`, а `DatabaseApi`, как минимум). Открывающую кавычку принято переносить на новую строчку. Это все мелочи, но я не вижу причин не делать их хорошо сразу. Соответствующие стандарты - [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/ru/), [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/ru/), ими сейчас пользуется все профессиональное сообщество. Для проверки собственного кода на соответствие стандартам форматирования можно использовать утилиту PHP Code Sniffer ([github](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) / [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/squizlabs/php_codesniffer)).
Вот на этом этапе:

```
public function get($table,$columns='*',$filter=false){
```

Код уже становится реально нечитаемым. Вы же понимаете, что экономить пробелы нет смысла?

Дальше - вот такие конструкции

```
$filter !== false
```

Должны быть такими:

```
!$filter
```

Нет смысла проверять на точное соответствие `false`, если все остальные `false`-приводимые значения ровно так же не могут быть использованы. Тернарные операторы зачастую упрощаются:

```
$string = $probablyFalse ?: ' WHERE ...';
```

При таком использовании вернется либо `false`, который при конкатенации превратится в пустую строку, либо необходимая строка. При желании еще можно поставить `(string)` перед тернаркой.

В этом случае `$filter` примет или значение `false`, или `' WHERE ...'`, а `false` при конкатенации станет пустой строкой.

```
//преобразовываем их в двух мерный массив и возвращаем
                           ^                      ^
//если переданные данные не являются ,не строкой и не числом преобразовываем их в json-данные
                              ^    ^^                      ^
```

Правила обычного человеческого языка, к сожалению, нужно выдерживать даже в комментариях.

```
gettype($val) !== 'string' || gettype($val) !== '"integer"'
```

Еще одна неправильная конструкция. Во-первых, `integer` в кавычках, во-вторых, что будет, если вы ошибетесь на символ в строке с типом (собственно, с кавычками так и произошло)? Программа будет работать неправильно, а дебаг будет довольно болезненным. В то же время в PHP есть готовые функции на проверку любого типа:

```
!is_string($val) || !is_int($val)
```

Следующая штука, которая напрягла:

```
$sql_data = substr($sql_data, 0, -1);//обрезаем лишнюю запятую
```

Вы не должны обрезать лишнюю запятую, вы *вообще не должны ее генерировать*. Во всех языках есть функционал склеивания строчного массива, в PHP это функция `implode($delimiter, $list)`, которая склеит вам этот массив.

По поводу таких конструкций:

```
"INSERT INTO `$table` ($keys) VALUES ($values)"
```

Существует функция `sprintf`, с помощью которой принято делать подобные штуки.
Она, конечно, произведет абсолютно идентичный эффект, но это несколько более
читаемый подход:

```
$query = sprintf('INSERT INTO `%s` (%s) VALUES (%s)', $table, $keys, $values);
```

По наименованию переменных: пишите их полностью, `$value` вместо `$val`,
`$config` вместо `$cfg`. От интерпретатора не убудет. А вот читать станет
приятней.

Последнее по форматированию и общему стилю - вот это вот запрещенный прием:

```
while(($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) != false) $results[] = $row;
```

По-хорошему он должен выглядеть так:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { // false-то зачем?
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

Пишите так, будто ваш потенциальный читатель двадцатый час поднимает сайт или
выхлестал полбутылки виски (а так оно и будет рано или поздно).

Теперь по наполнению: вы делаете класс для удобной работы с БД, абстрагируетесь
от нее. Но почему-то заставляете передавать условие и выборку полей строкой.
Зачем мне пользоваться таким классом, если я все равно пишу полстроки, которую
так бы написал целиком? В опенкарте есть такой же пример, доведенный до абсурда:

```
// index.php?route=product/product&product_id=42&limit=2
$url = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=42&limit=2');
```

Вот это условие:

```
if(gettype($val) !== 'string' || gettype($val) !== '"integer"') $val = json_encode($val);
```

Только по счастливой случайности пропустит `null`, как надо, и в то же время
вернет `false` и `true`, и только добрая воля MySQL сконвертировала бы их в `0`
и `1` соответственно. "Бы" - потому что строчка ниже по коду их воспримет и
обработает, как строку (плюс, опять, здесь нужен `sprintf`, это сложно читать):

```
else $sql_data = '`'.$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($key).'`=\''.$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($val).'\', ';
```

В результате, если в базу отправляется `false`, то вернется оттуда строка
`'false'`, которая никогда не будет воспринята PHP, как `false`. Это потеря
данных.

По названиям методов: есть общепринятая негласная конвенция наименования CRUD
(create, read, update, delete), зачем называть методы по-другому?

Последнее - это вот этот вот метод:

```
public function connect($cfg){//Функция подключения ,при вызове передаём настройки с данными от бд
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($cfg['bd']['host'], $cfg['bd']['user'], $cfg['bd']['password'], $cfg['bd']['name']);//подключение к бд
```

Во-первых, зачем там вообще лишний уровень вложенности с ключом `'bd'`?
Во-вторых, почему бы не предупредить ошибки на раннем уровне и заставить
пользователя передавать обязательные параметры?

```
public function connect($host, $name, $user, $password = null)
```

Ну и, конечно, уже сказали про инъекции и плейсхолдеры.

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой развёрнутый ответ, на счёт connect($cfg): Я пишу его для себя ,а я всегда использую в скриптах cfg, одного вида ,по этому сделал так.

Answer (score 1):

Класс для работы с mysql!
Обожаю классы для работы с mysql! Особенно на обед!

В сущности, ошибок тут немного, всего две:

1. Принципиальная архитектурная: это, на самом деле, никакой не класс для работы с mysql, а, скорее, такой недо-CRUD.
2. Чисто техническая: этим классом невозможно пользоваться в принцип - достаточно передать во WHERE условие, содержащее строку, и посмотреть, что будет.

Ну и защиты от инъекций он не обеспечивает никакой, но это уже мелочь, на фоне остального.

По первому пункту. Класс для работы с бд должен обеспечивать только выполнение запроса с подстановкой данных через плейсхолдеры, и возвращение результата, в нужном формате. Как мы видим, класс не делает ни того ни другого, в частности, формат данных только один. Хотя их должно быть минимум 4, а по-хорошему и больше.

В то же время класс замахивается на CRUD/query builder, но без основы в виде класса для работы с бд он просто нежизнеспособен.

По второму вопросу. Проблема происходит от весьма распространённого заблуждения, будто функция mysql(i)_real_escape_string защищает от каких бы то ни было инъекций, что, конечно же, совсем не так.

Для исправления ситуации рекомендую попрактиковаться в использовании PDO, которая как раз и является полноценным классом для работы с бд. И можно даже попробовать написать на ее основе CRUD, но только без чудовищной функции get, про которую я напишу чуть позже.

Еще из мелких, но важных замечаний - в классе отсутствует информирование об ошибках. К счастью, в mysqli это делается буквально одной строчкой,

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Которая пишется ДО коннекта